# Web application not uploading .docx files on some computers

Tags: c#

I have an application that allows a user to upload a document. This works on most people's computers, however some people they cannot upload .docx files.

I have tried to replicate this issue on PCs with the same OS, browser configuration, .docx file, etc, some allow the file to be uploaded and others throw a 'filetype not valid' error message. This has ruled out that it is a browser specific issue, but it could still be client-side somehow.

I can 'fix' this issue on the front-end of the website by adding in an extra file type `.docx` on the HTML validation.

Before

```
<input accept="application/msword, 
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, 
text/html, 
application/rtf, 
application/pdf, 
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text, 
text/plain" type="file">
```

After

```
<input accept="application/msword, 
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, 
text/html, 
application/rtf, 
application/pdf, 
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text, 
text/plain, 
.docx" type="file">
```

This allows .docx files to be selected in the explorer window of computers that previously did not allow docx files to be shown without clicking 'all files' from the dropdown.  However as 'docx' is not specifically a mime type it doesn't seem to work in the back-end code too as the affected computers still throw the 'file not valid' error.

```
  private const string AcceptedDocumentMimeTypes =
        "application/msword,
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, 
text/html, 
application/rtf, 
application/pdf, 
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text, 
text/plain, 
.docx";
```

It seems that some computers are having an issue with recognising `.docx` files with the `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` mime type? Maybe I am going in completely the wrong direction, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How would a computer with no word processing software installed know that a specific blob of bytes *is* a "application/msword" ?

Comment: Thank-you, it does seem that the issue is due to the PCs not having word installed. I will look into finding a way to get the server to accept these docx files knowing this.